# Overlapping intervals with partitions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Terminology:

I mean partitions of an interval, nothing fancy, eg $\mathcal{P}=\{[a,x],[x,b]\}$ would be a partition of $[a,b]$, there are many ways to denote partitions but that isn't important.

The length of an interval $l(I)$ is as you'd expect, $l([a,b])=b-a$, again nothing fancy.

**Problem**
I have a partition $\mathcal{P}_0$ of an interval $I$, suppose $minsize(\mathcal{P}_0)=\delta$ (where minsize is just "the smallest length of the intervals of $\mathcal{P}_0$)

I am dealing with another partition on the interval where $maxsize(\mathcal{P})\le \frac{\delta}{k}$, yes the max length of this one is $\le$ the minsize of $\mathcal{P}_0$.

There are two kinds of interval in $\mathcal{P}$, those which are contained in intervals of $\mathcal{P}_0$ and those which are not (ie, straddle the boundary).

The ones within intervals of $\mathcal{P}_0$ are convient for my purpose, I however need to say something about the ones which straddle boundaries.

I wish to show that the sum of the lengths of the intervals that straddle $\le \frac{l(I)}{k}$

**Things I have tried**

I first tried to see what I could say about the intervals, let's start with the first interval, suppose the first interval of $\mathcal{P}_0$ is $[a,x_1]$ and the first interval of $\mathcal{P}=[a,y_1]$, I found that:

$(k-1)maxsize(\mathcal{P})\le x1-y1$ which shows the two may coincide if $k=1$.

I then tried the interval $[x,y]$ say in $\mathcal{P}$ and the interval $[a,b]$ in $\mathcal{P}_0$, where $x<a$ and $y>a$ (so it straddles the a-side boundary) and found that: $y<b-(k-1)(y-x)$

I then tried a different approach **I HAVE JUST SEEN THE ANSWER, BUGGER**, I supposed that if $\mathcal{P}_0$ had $n$ partitions (so $n$ intervals who's union is I) then I have $n-1$ points where intervals may straddle.

For each of these straddling intervals, their length is $\le maxsize(\mathcal{P})$ by definition.

Couple this with the hypothesis we see that the sum of the straddling lengths is $\le (n-1)\frac{minsize(\mathcal{P_0})}{k}$

But $n*minsize(\mathcal{P}_0)\le l(I)$, so this is $\le \frac{l(I)}{k}$

Right?