# Why is this 2 here (I believe I have shown it without it) - integration (Riemann integral)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

[image]

I am looking at Proposition 1.3 (on page 3, how embarrassing!)

The line I dispute is $I_\mathcal{P}(f)\le I_{\mathcal{P}_1}(f)+\frac{2M}{k}l(I)$

I see no need at all for the 2!

Logic:

$I_\mathcal{P}=\sum \sup_{J_k}(f(x)) l(J_k)$. The intervals of $\mathcal{P}$ properly contained in $\mathcal{P}_0$'s intervals will be intervals of the common refinement $\mathcal{P}_1$.

So $I_\mathcal{P}=\sum_{\text{ones properly contained}} + \sum_{\text{ones not properly contained}}$ and the ones properly contained will agree with a portion of $I_{\mathcal{P}_1}$. Thus:

$I_\mathcal{P}\le I_{\mathcal{P}_1} + \sum_{\text{ones not properly contained}}$

Thus:
$\sup_{H_k}(f(x))$ (where $H_k$ is an interval not properly contained in $\mathcal{P}_0$) is $\le \sup_I(f(x))$ which is $\le \sup_I(|f(x)|)$

Thus:
$I_\mathcal{P}\le I_{\mathcal{P}_1} + \sup_I(|f(x)|)\sum_{\text{lengths of ones not properly contained}}=I_{\mathcal{P}_1} + M\sum_{\text{lengths of ones not properly contained}}$

But as is established [Overlapping intervals with partitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107710/overlapping-intervals-with-partitions) there, the sum of the lengths of the not properly contained ones is $\le \frac{l(I)}{k}$

So we see:

$I_\mathcal{P}\le I_{\mathcal{P}_1} + \sup_I(|f(x)|)\sum_{\text{lengths of ones not properly contained}}\le I_{\mathcal{P}_1} + M\frac{l(I)}{k}$

and the result follows.

**This makes perfect sense** The biggest contribution the intervals could give is $M$ * their lengths, not 2 times this!

So my question is: why is the 2 there?!

Comment: BTW I get that the presence of the 2 is just as valid (it makes the inequalities bigger!) but the 2 is not used at all, ever.

Answer (score 0):

Consider one of these subintervals, $H_j$, that contains one of the endpoints of $\mathcal{P}_0$. $H_j$ comprises $2$ subintervals in $\mathcal{P}_1$; let's call them $A_j$ and $B_j$.

Suppose that $\sup\limits_{A_j}{f(x)} = M$ and $\sup\limits_{B_j}{f(x)} = -M$. Function $f$ could be a step function, for example. Then the difference in area in $B_j$ between $I_{P}$ and $I_{P_1}$ is $Ml(B_j) - (-Ml(B_j)) = 2Ml(B_j)$.

It's possible that this occurs on $H_j$ for all $j$ and for each of them, we have $l(A_j)$ close to $0$ so that $l(B_j)$ is close to $l(H_j)$. Then $\sum_j{2Ml(B_j)}$ can be close to $2Ml(I)/k$, which is the term in their inequality.